# How to combine elements of List type properties of another list elements into one list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a list of elements of some type A:

```
List<A> listA;
```

And each A class has a member which is a list of type B:

```
class A
{
    List<B> listB;
}
```

What should be my LINQ query to combine all `B` elements of all `listB`s from `A` elements in the `listA`? Of course I can traverse through the `listA` and keep adding to a new `List<B>` all `listB`s, but I'd like to get it done by LINQ query.

Comment: You can flatten heirarchies with `SelectMany` for example `listA.SelectMany(a => a.listB)` would give you a `IEnumerable<B>`.

Comment: Yea, already found it in MS docs, your answer is absolutely right. Push it to be an answer so I can mark it as an answer @juharr. Thanks